# How to make a tab active when it is clicked on in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Good day,
I'm trying to write code to make a tab active when it is clicked on in my React App with Bootstrap. I had previously set only the Home Tab to be active but now I want to change the code. Please how do I go about this? I am new to React.

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faCoffee, faCut } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = {
        count: this.props.value,
        tabs:["Home","About","Contact","FAQ"]
    };

    assets={
        images:{
            image1:"images/la.jpg",
            image2:"images/chicago.jpg",
            image3:"images/ny.jpg"
        },
        font:{
            font1:"Roboto",
            font2:"sans-serif",
            font3:"Verdana"
        },
        styles:{
            fontSize:12,
            fontWeight:'bold',
            fontColor:'whitesmoke'
            
        },
        imgstyle:{
            borderRadius:"50%",
            width:"100px",
            height:"100px",
            marginTop:"10px"
        }
    }

    formatCount=()=>{
        const count=this.state.count;
        return count===0?"Zero":count;
    };
    handleIncrement=()=>{
        this.setState({count:this.state.count + 1})
    };
    styles={
        fontSize:15,
        fontWeight:"bold"
        
    }
    renderTags=()=>{
        return(
            <nav className="nav nav-tabs">
                {this.state.tabs.map(tab=>(
                <a href="#" key={tab} className={this.activeNav(tab)}>
                    {tab}
                </a>
                ))}
            </nav>
            );
    };
    formatBadge=()=>{
        let classes="badge m-2 badge-";
        classes+=this.state.count===0?"warning":"success";
        return classes;
    };

/*MAKES HOME TAB ACTIVE*/
   activeNav=(navlink)=>{
    if (navlink==="Home"){
        return "nav-item nav-link active"}
    else{
        return "nav-item nav-link"}
    };

    render() {
        console.log('props',this.props.value)
        return (
            <div>
                <span style={this.styles} className={this.formatBadge()}>
                    {this.formatCount()}
                </span>
                <button onClick={this.handleIncrement} className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary m-2"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} className="mr-2"/>Increment</button>
                
                
                <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2" onClick={()=>this.props.deleteThis(this.props.id)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCut} className="mr-2"/>Delete</button>
                <img style={this.assets.imgstyle} src={this.assets.images.image1} alt=""/>
                {this.renderTags()}
                
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Counter;
```

Any help regarding this would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Code output]

Comment: considering your tabs resemble pages, I'd recommend using React router. here are some reads: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: @zergski thank you but I'm not familiar with JQuery. I would like to accomplish this with JavaScript.

Comment: no, no jQuery.. this is a react component.

Comment: @zergski there's a bit of jquery in the code. I would like to write a function in Javascript to do this

Comment: Are you just looking to add the `active` className to the tab that is clicked?

Comment: @Akhil yes that is what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the active tab when you click on it, there are three things you need to do:

- Maintain a state to track the active tab and move the tabs array out of the state since they are static.

```js
tabs = ["Home", "About", "Contact", "FAQ"];
state = {
  count: this.props.value,
  activeTabId: 0
};
```

- Change the active tab id when a tab is clicked.

```js
onClick = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    activeTabId: id
  });
};
renderTags = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="nav nav-tabs">
      {this.tabs.map((tab, id) => (
        <a
          href="#"
          key={tab}
          onClick={() => this.onClick(id)}
          className={this.activeNav(id)}
        >
          {tab}
        </a>
      ))}
    </nav>
  );
};
```

- Use the changed state in your tab styling function.

```js
activeNav = (id) => {
  if (id === this.state.activeTabId) {
    return "nav-item nav-link active";
  } else {
    return "nav-item nav-link";
  }
};
```

You can find the full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-3sevw?file=/index.js:0-2761).

Having said that, there are a couple of things you could do better. You could just ditch the class and use functions for component and use [react hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) for handling your states once you do that.